# Обновить Qt Creator

Tags: qt, qtcreator

Для обновления компонентов используют *MaintenanceTool*, который подключается к их серверам и докачивает необходимые файлы, но у меня провайдер блокирует как половину их сайта, так и сервер, и я получаю ошибку подключения[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я хочу обновить Qt Creator до последней стабильной версии, потому что в моей 4.3.1 есть пара багов. Может есть репозитории на других серверах?

Comment: найдите себе проксю и пропишите в настройки. А что за провайдер такой, что решил заблокировать Qt?

Comment: также есть вариант выкачать оффлайн-дистрибутив

Comment: @KoVadim Не могу прокси, это рабочая сеть, а провайдер - Nline.

Comment: то, что это рабочая сеть, не запрещает использовать прокси для одного приложения. А сайт провайдера тоже похоже заблокирован